# Different items are getting active and selected instead of one item

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-redux, semantic-ui-react

I have implemented a react semantic ui dropdown in a react application which is searchable. The dropdown works fine if a select any item by clicking on it. But when I select the element by search text in the drop down the element matching the search text gets the class as `active`and the element at the index position of that element get the class set as `selected`, where as the expected behaviour is that the element with the matching text should only get both the classes `active` and `selected`.

JS:

```
import React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";

const countryOptions = [
  { key: "af", value: "af", flag: "af", text: "Afghanistan" },
  { key: "ax", value: "ax", flag: "ax", text: "Aland Islands" },
  { key: "al", value: "al", flag: "al", text: "Albania" },
  { key: "dz", value: "dz", flag: "dz", text: "Algeria" },
  { key: "as", value: "as", flag: "as", text: "American Samoa" }
];

const DropdownExampleSearchSelection = () => (
  <Dropdown
    search
    options={countryOptions}
    open
    scrolling
    tabIndex={-1}
    wrapSelection={true}
  />
);

export default DropdownExampleSearchSelection;
```

HTML :

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Expected code snippet :[semantic-ui-example-zd7h6](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-zd7h6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: added a sample code snippet of the expected behaviour.

Comment: Not a separate link...the code has to be **in the question**.

Comment: Updated with addition of code.

Comment: I do not see a tabIndex in the working example. Did you try removing it?

Comment: Yes, I tried removing it but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/pull/3405) when using styled elements as a trigger for `Popup` , `Modal` and `Sidebar` in `semantic-ui-react`. This is a [work around](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3786#issuecomment-532175831) to fix that

```
const ButtonWithRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Ref innerRef={ref}>
    <Button {...props} />
  </Ref>
));

export const WorkingButton = styled(ButtonWithRef)`
  color: green !important;
`;
```

Sandbox link : [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-oxqmt)
Original author : [layershifter](https://github.com/layershifter)